# Why does regex match the symbol "m"

Tags: regex

This regex matches the last "m" from the example input. How to avoid this matching?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/WZmdfH/2/

Tried Regex: `[^:](\/\/)` 
Tried Input: `https://www.example.com//`

I'm expecting that the regex finds all double slashes (`//`) except the first in `https://`.

I want to replace all `//` in urls like `https://example.com/123/345//123//909` (except the first)

Comment: You are searching for something that is *not* `:` *and* is followed by `//` which is satisfied by `m//`. What exactly do you want to match? Can you give a better example of what you want do like match domain name etc?

Comment: i'm waiting that it regex finded all '//' exclud first // https://

Comment: Give an example of what you need? I am not able to understand what you mean :). Modify the question with the exact output you need.

Comment: i need replace all // in in url https://www.example.com/123/345//123//909 excluded first // https: **//** www.example.com/123/345//123//909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *negative* *lookbehind* to achieve this:

`(?<!:)(\/\/)`

If you want to be more precise, you can include `http(s)` as well:

`(?<!https:|http:)\/\/`

See this [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ng1D5c/2) example.